# converting phone letters to numbers and using while loop

Tags: python-3.x

I am currently writing function that takes in a string and converts that string (which is a phone number) into numbers only. In addition I am also using a while loop asking the user if they want to continue. My output is only showing me the first number or letter I type in, I want to know why. This is what I have so far:

```
def translate_num(convert):
answer=input('insert  y to continue')
convert=input('Enter phone number here')
while answer=='y':
    for word in convert:
        phone_num=[]
        if word == 'A' or word == 'B' or word == 'C':
           phone_num.append('2')
        elif word == 'D' or word == 'E' or word == 'F':
           phone_num.append('3')
        elif word == 'G' or word == 'H' or word == 'I':
           phone_num.append('4')
        elif word == 'J' or word == 'K' or word == 'L':
           phone_num.append('5')
        elif word == 'M' or word == 'N' or word == 'O':
           phone_num.append('6')
        elif word == 'P' or word == 'Q' or word == 'R' or word== 'S':
           phone_num.append('7')
        elif word == 'T' or word == 'U' or word == 'V':
           phone_num.append('8')
        elif word == 'W' or word == 'X' or word == 'Y' or word=='Z':
           phone_num.append('9')
        else:
            phone_num.append(word)
        print(phone_num)
        answer=input('insert y to continue')
        return 
    translate_num('555-361-FOOD')
```

Comment: That's because the return statement is inside the while, so you return at the end of the first iteration. Move it out by de-indenting it backwards for spaces.

Comment: I moved over the return statement but now it is only showing one number at a time.

Answer (score 0):

you are re-initializing the `phone_num` with `phone_num=[]` value after going through each value in `convert`. Instead declare `phone_num=[]` once at the start of the function, also as pointed out by kabanus the return statement needs to be de-intended by a block. My implementation below seems to work (I have removed the redundant input statements since you are already calling the function, I have also added code to convert the number list back to a string :

```
def translate_num(convert):
    #answer=input('insert  y to continue')
    #convert=input('Enter phone number here')
    phone_num=[]
    while True:
    for word in convert:

        if word == 'A' or word == 'B' or word == 'C':
           phone_num.append('2')
        elif word == 'D' or word == 'E' or word == 'F':
           phone_num.append('3')
        elif word == 'G' or word == 'H' or word == 'I':
           phone_num.append('4')
        elif word == 'J' or word == 'K' or word == 'L':
           phone_num.append('5')
        elif word == 'M' or word == 'N' or word == 'O':
           phone_num.append('6')
        elif word == 'P' or word == 'Q' or word == 'R' or word== 'S':
           phone_num.append('7')
        elif word == 'T' or word == 'U' or word == 'V':
           phone_num.append('8')
        elif word == 'W' or word == 'X' or word == 'Y' or word=='Z':
           phone_num.append('9')
        else:
            phone_num.append(word)
        #print(phone_num)
        #answer=input('insert y to continue')
    number=''    
    for item in phone_num:
        number=number+str(item)
    return (number) 

print (translate_num('555-361-FOOD'))
```